# Update global variable on scroll event angular 5

Tags: scroll, global-variables, angular5, addeventlistener, updating

I'm working on angular 5 application. I want to update a variable when the page is scrolling, but the problem is when I put console log inside the scope, the variable is updated but in Dom is not.
component:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll')   public windowScrolling(): void {
    this.isMenuOpen = false;
    console.log(this.isMenuOpen)    // false   }
```

DOM:

```
{{isMenuOpen}}  // true
```

I guess the variable inside the scope becomes local variable but I have no idea how to make it global on scroll event. I really appreciate if somebody has any solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Implement like this**.

ngOnInit() {
            window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
                this.scroll(e);
            }.bind(this), true);
        }

scroll(event: any) {
   console.log(event)
   this.isMenuOpen = false;
   console.log(this.isMenuOpen)
}
```